# Extract some characters before specific symbol in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have an email address, for example **hello.world123@e-mail.com** and I want to extract first 3 characters and 3 characters before symbol **@**, for example I should get **hel123**.
Second exampe: **m2atos.doga55@usa.com** - the result should be: **m2aa55**

The first part is easy - *=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;3))* - I get first 3 characters.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxq47.png)

The second part - I can get all the characters before the symbol **@** - *=LEFT(A1; FIND("@";A1)-1)*
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fSun.png)

But I cannot combine them or modify just to get first 3 characters and 3 characters before symbol **@**.

Comment: You need to use the `MID` function like this:  `=CONCATENATE(left(A1,3),MID(A1,find("@",A1,1)-3,3))`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=index(if(A1:A<>"",regexreplace(A1:A,"(...).*(...)@.*","$1$2"),))`

Answer (score 0):

what should happen if it's shorter than 6 characters?
This works but errors out if the initial is less than 6 chars.

```
=REPLACE(SPLIT(A1,"@"),4,FIND("@",A1)-7,)
```